# Adding an annotation that can only apply for recursive methods

Tags: java, recursion, annotations, data-science

Java has the `@override` annotation which only applies for overriden methods. and it gives a compiler error if you apply it for something else.

In my project I am trying to use some thing similar. Since the project uses recursion too much. I created an annotation called `@recurisve` and I add it before recursive functions

It won't be a big deal but I'd love if there's a way to make it actually detect recursive functions

Comment: The compiler _knows_ about the `@Override` annotation, but not about your custom one. So what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with recursion (see quick sort)  What is it you want to avoid ?

Comment: I don't see how it could help, but you might be interested in iterative functions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)#Recursion_versus_iteration

Answer (score 0):

The problem to discover recursive functions never seems too hard to solve, the function body just has to be scanned for the function name.
Due to namespaces the problem is getting a bit more complex and for a simple linter not solvable reliable, but if "this->functionName()" or "self::functionName()" are discovered it should be reliable probably.